# How can I make a JSON POST request with LWP?

Tags: perl, json, http-post, lwp

If you try to login at https://orbit.theplanet.com/Login.aspx?url=/Default.aspx (use any username/password combination), you can see that the login credentials are sent as a non-traditional set of POST data: just a lonesome JSON string and no normal key=value pair.

Specifically, instead of:

```
username=foo&password=bar
```

or even something like:

```
json={"username":"foo","password":"bar"}
```

There's simply:

```
{"username":"foo","password":"bar"}
```

Is it possible to perform such a request with `LWP` or an alternative module? I am prepared to do so with `IO::Socket` but would prefer something more high-level if available.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You'll need to construct the HTTP request manually and pass that to LWP. Something like the following should do it:

```
my $uri = 'https://orbit.theplanet.com/Login.aspx?url=/Default.aspx';
my $json = '{"username":"foo","password":"bar"}';
my $req = HTTP::Request->new( 'POST', $uri );
$req->header( 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' );
$req->content( $json );
```

Then you can execute the request with LWP:

```
my $lwp = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$lwp->request( $req );
```

Comment: My search leading to this was using the vanilla GET/POST method , and it might not be obvious from the json snippet, so I dare to contribute also the GET/POST usage `new HTTP::Request(        'GET' => "http://url/path",        ['Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'],       'par1=par1value&par2=par2value'   );`

Answer (score 16):

Just create a POST request with that as the body, and give it to LWP.

```
my $req = HTTP::Request->new(POST => $url);
$req->content_type('application/json');
$req->content($json);

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new; # You might want some options here
my $res = $ua->request($req);
# $res is an HTTP::Response, see the usual LWP docs.
```

Comment: print $res->decoded_content should print the decoded response

Answer (score 14):

The page is just using an "anonymized" (without name) input, which happens to be in JSON format.

You should be able to use [$ua->post($url, ..., Content => $content)](http://search.cpan.org/dist/libwww-perl/lib/LWP/UserAgent.pm), which in turn use the POST() function from [HTTP::Request::Common](http://search.cpan.org/~ether/HTTP-Message-6.10/lib/HTTP/Request/Common.pm).

```
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $url = 'https://orbit.theplanet.com/Login.aspx?url=/Default.aspx';
my $json = '{"username": "foo", "password": "bar"}';

my $ua = new LWP::UserAgent();
$response = $ua->post($url, Content => $json);

if ( $response->is_success() ) {
    print("SUCCESSFUL LOGIN!\n");
}
else {
    print("ERROR: " . $response->status_line());
}
```

Alternatively, you can also use an hash for the JSON input:

```
use JSON::XS qw(encode_json);

...

my %json;
$json{username} = "foo";
$json{password} = "bar";

...

$response = $ua->post($url, Content => encode_json(\%json));
```

Comment: I believe you are missing the content-type setting for the "post" function - I don't think LWP guesses it and it defaults to 'x-www-form-urlencoded'

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use WWW::Mechanize you can set the header 'content-type' before post

```
$mech->add_header( 
'content-type' => 'application/json'
);

$mech->post($uri, Content => $json);
```