# How to POST content with an HTTP Request (Perl)

Tags: perl, http, lwp

```
use LWP::UserAgent;
use Data::Dumper;

my $ua = new LWP::UserAgent;
$ua->agent("AgentName/0.1 " . $ua->agent);
my $req = new HTTP::Request POST => 'http://example.com';
$req->content('port=8', 'target=64'); #problem
my $res = $ua->request($req);

print Dumper($res->content);
```

How can I send multiple pieces of content using $req->content? What kind of data does $req->content expect?

It only sends the last one.

Edit:

Found out if i format it like 'port=8&target=64' it works. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
my $ua      = LWP::UserAgent->new(); 
my $request = POST( $url, [ 'port' => 8, 'target' => 64 ] ); 
my $content = $ua->request($request)->as_string();
```

Comment: Despite the code in the question I'd go with a full OOP approach:  `my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(); my $response = $ua->post($url, $parameter); my $content = $response->as_string();`

Answer (score 4):

The answer given didn't work for me.  I still had the same problem as OP.

The documentation for [LWP::UserAgent](http://search.cpan.org/~ether/libwww-perl-6.15/lib/LWP/UserAgent.pm) wants a hash or array reference.

This works:

```
my $url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
my $ua      = LWP::UserAgent->new(); 

my %form;
$form{'secret'}='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$form{'response'}=$captchaResponse;

my $response = $ua->post( $url, \%form ); 
my $content = $response->as_string();
```

Answer (score 3):

Using together LWP::UserAgent and HTTP::Request  as it is also quite common if not even more frequent practice , I was little puzzled that the standard POST and GET / request were almost not discussed at SO aside from json as them are in vast majority used.

POST

```
    my $ua  = LWP::UserAgent->new();
    my $req = new HTTP::Request( 
       'POST' => "http://url/path", 
       ['Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'],
       'par1=par1value&par2=par2value'
    );
    $ua->request($req);
```

similarly for the GET

```
    my $ua  = LWP::UserAgent->new();
    my $req = new HTTP::Request( 
       'GET' => "http://url/path", 
       ['Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'],
       'par1=par1value&par2=par2value' # or I presume attaching the query string directly to the url
    );
    $ua->request($req);
```

another format form , where the first two parameters (method and url) are not fused into a one, not like the previous, but separately

```
my $request = HTTP::Request->new( 'POST', $url, [ parameter1 => 'parameter1Value' ] );
request->header( 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' )
```

There is a similar question, but just regards LWP and Json, but it could be probably accomplished only by using both LWP and HTTP::Request together as suggested by that question chosen answer, and the POST and GET were missing there but it might not have been obvious

[How can I make a JSON POST request with LWP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4199266/how-can-i-make-a-json-post-request-with-lwp)

Note:
I post this specially also, since the concrete/concise usage for POST/GET is not mentioned even in the documentation
https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Request