# Best way to send content in PERL POST Request?

Tags: perl, http, server

I am sending a PERL `POST Request` over `HTTPS`. During sending the request i need to send two things in content one is an authorization token and other is the command need to be executed on the server side.

What should be the approach to send these two things as the content?

Should it be:-

```
$request->content($token) 
$request->content($command)
```

OR should it be

```
my @content =($token,$command) 
$request->content(\@content)
```

The module which i am using is `LWP::UserAgent` and in that i will be creating a `HTTP::Request` type object `my $request = HTTP::Request->new(POST => "<url>");` and in 
this object i am sending content.

Comment: I think a bit more context is needed - what modules are you using to send (and receive) the POSTed data?

Comment: sorry i forget to give module details. Edited my question above. :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to POST content with an HTTP Request (Perl)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11264470/how-to-post-content-with-an-http-request-perl)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only a single content (request body) for a POST request. So any call of `content` just replaces the previously defined content. Please have a look at the [documentation for LWP::UserAgent::post](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent#ua-post-url-form) which clearly defines how to send POST data with multiple values. Also, it might be useful if you understand how forms in HTML work, both on the client (browser) and on the server side. Because only if you know what the server side expects in detail you can create the proper request.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and further suggestion :)